# Create web Application with google app engine?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, web-applications

I am new to web application development. I developed an android app which uses the Google app engine Module as a server. I want to connect this app engine server to my web Application means both the application uses one backend. How can I achieve this. Please guide me and give me your helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One classic way to connect an HTML front-end (i.e. your website) to an App Engine back-end is by using the Google JavaScript client library https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

Romin Irani has nice tutorials on this method, see https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1-b571ad6c7cd2#.sbsqvfu3n and in particular Part 4 https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-4-37ea3aac7948#.ivyo2i4pb

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine will host your website, I suggest you read their documentations first before you make your decision to start configuring your app with Google App Engine as it can be real pain to get it all working in the initial run.

Google App Engine will provide you with the system and power to run your web app. Their standard environment supports Java, Python, PHP, and Go. Additionally, your website templates can include JavaScript along with your HTML which, among other things, allows you to write AJAX-enabled web applications.

I think their FAQ will help you get started.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/